# Using Kotlin multiplatform js file into war project

Tags: javascript, kotlin, war, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I have a multimodule gradle build with these two modules:
- Module A -> JVM/War build
- Module B -> Kotlin multiplatform with JVM and JS target

When I build Module B, I will get a js file. I want to include that js file into the webapp folder of Module A. But I have no idea how I can do this.

Can somebody tell me how to do this?